# hideTab doesn't work when tabsetPanel and hideTab are inside an observer in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm traying to create an app that reads some user and password and then create a `tabsetPanel` inside a `renderUI`.
The app is supposed to read a code and type number from a data base and if the type is 1 then hides some `tabPanel`, however all the tabpanels are always shown.

```r
library(shiny)
library(RPostgreSQL)

con=dbConnect(........)

ui <- fluidPage(

  textInput("user","User:"),
  passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
  actionButton("go", "Go",class = "btn-primary"),

  uiOutput("panel")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent({input$go}, {
    code<-dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT type FROM table")[[1]]
    #code is a number

    if(dim(code)[1]==1){
      type=reactive(dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT type FROM table2")[[1]])
      #type() is a number

      output$panel=renderUI(
        tabsetPanel(id = "tab",
                  tabPanel("Tab1"),
                  tabPanel("Tab2")     
                  )
      )

      observe({
        if(type()==1){
          hideTab(inputId = "tab", target = "Tab1")
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem is that de observer is executed before the renderUI and doesn't re-execute, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you've mixed up 3 different processes.

1. Checking the user has access can be put in a separate function, outside of the scope of `server`, simply returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` (and possibly an error).
2. Dynamically loading the tabs. If this must only occur *after* the user has logged in, you can simply opt to *not* display Tab1. If the tabs has to be loaded regardless (but still dynamically), put it outside of the scope of `observeEvent({input$go}, {...})`. Consider, just for now, to setup the tabsetpanel with tabs in the `ui`.
3. Showing/hiding the tab.

Within a reactive/observe, you do not need to use additional reactives. They already are set to run. So `type` should be just be `type = dbGetQuery(...)`, and the `observe` nested within an `observe`/`observeEvent` makes no sense.

Lastly, to debug why the tab is not hidden, use the good ol' fashioned `print` and look at your console. Try updating to

```
  observe({
    cat('Testing type: ', type(), '\n')
    if(type()==1){
      cat('Hiding tab...\n')
      hideTab(inputId = "tab", target = "Tab1")
    }
  })
```

and watch out for those messages in your console. Are they printed? Then the fault might be on the client-side (perhaps you mispelled something). Are the messages missing? Then you know the code never executed, and you'll have to investigate why.

**Update:**

Looking further into the matters, try using the browsers Inspect-function. For the viewer in Rstudio (and Chrome), you can right-click and select "Inspect element". A new window appears (or is docked within the window), which allows you to inspect the HTML DOM and view the JavaScript console. Here, we notice an important message:

> Uncaught There is no tabsetPanel (or navbarPage or navlistPanel) with id equal to 'tab'

Simply put, the `hideTab` command is sent *before* the client has finished loading the tabpanels.

One solution, that did not work, is as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  type <- reactiveVal(0)
  type_delayed <- debounce(type, Inf)

  observeEvent({input$go}, {



    code<-data.frame(code=1)
    #code is a number

    if(dim(code)[1]==1){
      #type(dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT type FROM table2")[[1]])
      type(1)
      #type() is a number

      output$panel=renderUI(
        tabsetPanel(id = "tab",
                  tabPanel("Tab1"),
                  tabPanel("Tab2")     
                  )
      )


    }
  })

  observe({
        cat('Testing type: ', type_delayed(), '\n')
        if( type_delayed() ==1){
          cat('Hiding tab...\n')
          hideTab(inputId = "tab", target = "Tab1")
        }
      })
}
```

I.e., we delay the execution of hiding the tab. Except it's a bad solution, because you have to choose a timing that is as soon as possible, but not so soon that the client isn't ready.

I suggest the following solution: Instead of hiding the panel, don't add it until you need it:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

 textInput("user","User:"),
 passwordInput("password", "Password:"),
 actionButton("go", "Go",class = "btn-primary"),
 actionButton("add", "Add tab"),

 uiOutput("panel")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  i <- 1

  observeEvent({input$go}, {



    code<-data.frame(code=1)
    #code is a number

    if(dim(code)[1]==1){
      #type <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT type FROM table2")[[1]]
      type <- 1
      #type() is a number

      output$panel=renderUI({
        if (type == 1) {
          i <<- 1
          tabsetPanel(
            id = "tab",
            tabPanel("Tab1")
          )
        } else {
          i <<- 2
          tabsetPanel(
            id = "tab",
            tabPanel("Tab1"),tabPanel("Tab2")
          ) 
        }

      })


    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    i <<- i + 1
    appendTab('tab', tabPanel(paste0('Tab', i)))
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, you are right about the reactivity  but I've tried and both messages are printed, but the tabpanel is shown and I don't shee any misspell.

Comment: I don't want to add another button